# Why does Wordpress give me this error instead of my website?

Tags: wordpress

I am getting this error on my website:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/mgsells/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-walker.php on line 263`

But no website.

I have tried copying and pasting the error in here but none works. 
My site had either a hacked plugin that was a malicious redirect or someone hacked it.

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/mgsells/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-walker.php on line 263`

The error stays the same unless I try other code on another line.

Comment: What's the full error?

Comment: That's all it says on the site.

Comment: we can't help much without the full error, it's something to do with navigation menu.

Comment: Trun on debug in wp-config.php, if this don't help try deleting and reuploading `wp-admin` and `wp-includes` (sames version as current installed in your server). if this not working change theme to default, you might have custom walker function wit some kind of error.